# next.js @reduxjs/toolkit useSelector return undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux, next.js

js and @reduxjs/toolkit in my project.
When I try to get data from store with useSelector method, undefined value returns.

here my reducer file:

```
import { createSlice } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";
export const deviceSlice = createSlice({
  name: "isMobile",
  initialState: {
    value: false,
  },
  reducers: {
    detectDevice: (state) => {
      state.value = !state.value;
    },
  },
});
export const { detectDevice } = deviceSlice.actions;

export default deviceSlice.reducer;
```

here my store.js file :

```
    import { configureStore } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";
    import { detectDevice } from "./device";
    export default configureStore({
      reducer: {
        isMobile: detectDevice,
      },
    });
```

and my index.js file :

```
import Head from "next/head";
import Nav from "../components/nav/Nav";
import { useEffect } from "react";
import { useSelector, useDispatch } from "react-redux";
import { detectDevice } from "../redux/device";

export default function Home() {
  const dispatchDetectDevice = useDispatch();
  let size = useSelector((state) => state.isMobile.value);
  useEffect(() => {
    if (window.innerWidth < 576) dispatchDetectDevice(detectDevice(true));
    else {
      dispatchDetectDevice(detectDevice(false));
    }
    console.log(size);
  });
  return (
    <div>
      <Head>
        <title>Create Next App</title>
        <meta name="description" content="Generated by create next app" />
        <link rel="icon" href="/favicon.ico" />
      </Head>
      <Nav />
    </div>
  );
}
```

The console.log() method on line 15 returns undefined value.

What do you think is the reason for this?

Comment: Is `Home` being wrapped by the Redux store provider?

Answer (score 0):

Your global state cannot be accessed unless your application has been wrapped with the `Redux store`'s `provider`. This could explain why your `size` is `undefined`.

I don't see any issues on your `store.js` nor `device.js` files.

Could you please enclose your `_app.js` file?

This should be in it:

```
import { Provider } from "react-redux";
import store from "PATH_TO_YOUR_STORE";

function MyApp({ Component, pageProps }) {
   return (
    <Provider store={store}>
      <Component {...pageProps} />
    </Provider>
  )
}
export default MyApp;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using `return` statement in `useSelector` function like:

```
let size = useSelector((state) => return state.isMobile.value);
```

and also check if you're providing store properly to the whole app.
Hope this will fix your error and if you need any help do take time to read the official guide on redux-toolkit usage with Nextjs.